# How to separate values by ";" in foreach loop for each item using C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, foreach

I have a foreach loop iterating each item at a time, I want to separate each item by using ";"
But not adding ";" for the last item. 
I have tried using String.Join(";", item), But it did not work for me.

I get the output as : SN-123SN-456SN-789

Output should look something like this: **SN-123;SN-456;SN-789**

Please find my code below:

```cs
if (siteId != "null")
{
    var siteList = this.feeDataAccess.GetSitesListById(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, siteId);
    List<string> siteSNlist = siteList.Gateways.Select(x => x.SerialNumber).ToList();
    foreach (var item in siteSNlist)
    {
        siteSN += String.Join(";", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `string.Join` in a loop? You just need `string result = string.Join(";", siteSNlist);` Note that "it did not work" isn't nearly as useful as showing your expected result and actual result. Likewise half of the code you've shown isn't actually relevant - a [mcve] would make this question better.

Comment: But I have to add each item next to the first item.

Comment: But that's what `string.Join` does... did you try it? Did you read the documentation for what `string.Join` does? (If I'm missing something about your requirements, that's a hint that a [mcve] would make it clearer...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use string join for a collection, try like this:

```
if (siteId != "null")
{
  var siteList = this.feeDataAccess.GetSitesListById(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, siteId);
  List<string> siteSNlist = siteList.Gateways.Select(x => x.SerialNumber).ToList();
                
  siteSN = String.Join(";", siteSNlist);
                
}
```

For the nested objects you can use select:

```
if (partnerId != "null")
{
    var partnerList = this.feeDataAccess.GetPartnerListbyId(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, partnerId);
    foreach (var item in partnerList)
    {
        var partnerSN = string.Join(";", item.Gateways.Select(x => x.SerialNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: How does String.join work in this case? ```if (partnerId != "null")
            {
                var partnerList = this.feeDataAccess.GetPartnerListbyId(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, partnerId);
                foreach (var item in partnerList)
                {
                    foreach (var gateways in item.Gateways)
                    {
                        var partnersGW = gateways.SerialNumber;
                        partnerSN += partnersGW;
                    }
                }
            }```

Comment: @Philip I have added it to the answer

Comment: I have tried this, But did not work. This just returns me single value. "SN-123"

Comment: That's because your Gateways contains 1 element

Comment: I need to append it if there is more number of gateways. example : Gateway1 has SN-123 and Gateway2 has SN-456. then my output should be "SN-123;SN-456"

Comment: If you don't want us to go back-and-forth forever, you really should add a minimal reproducible example, including sample contents of those Gateways.

Answer (score 1):

String.Join can Concatenates the members of a constructed System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 collection of type System.String, using the specified separator between each member. So we can use list directly in Join.

```
List<string> siteSNlist = new List<string>() { "SN-123", "SN-124", "SN-125" , "SN-126"};

string siteSN = string.Join(";", siteSNlist);
```

**Output** : SN-123;SN-124;SN-125;SN-126